# Replace a string in all files under current directory and sub-directories

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to replace a string `A/comp with B/comp` under current directory and sub-directories.

I tried issuing this
`find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/A/Comp/B/comp/g' {} \;`

But the `/` delimiter seems to be erroneous and doesn't replace the string that is intended.

Answer (score 0):

The `s` command in `sed` is not bound to `/` as the delimiter:

> `s/BRE/replacement/flags`
>
> Substitute the replacement string for instances of the BRE in the pattern space. Any character other than <backslash> or <newline> can be used instead of a <slash> to delimit the BRE and the replacement. Within the BRE and the replacement, the BRE delimiter itself can be used as a literal character if it is preceded by a <backslash>.

<sup>([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html))</sup>

- Either use a delimiter that does not appear in `A/comp` and `B/comp`, e.g.:

  ```
  s|A/comp|B/comp|g
  ```

  You choose the delimiter. Even `sZA/compZB/compZg` or `s A/comp B/comp g` will do.
- Or if you choose to stick to `/`, escape every `/` character that should be taken literally:

  ```
  s/A\/comp/B\/comp/g
  ```